# @Cacheable annotation does not work after migrating to WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2.
I used to cache values to Redis with `@Cacheable` annotation like that:

```
    @Cacheable("companyCacheManager")
    public Company getCompany(String id, String value) {
        return getOneCompany(id, value);
    }
```

After migrating `spring-boot-starter-web` to `spring-boot-starter-webflux` without changing code `@Cacheable` annotation does not work anymore.

Is any alternative for that in WebFlux?

**UPD**

Migration `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` to `spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive` did not help.

Comment: You haven't shown how this integrates with the rest of your code, but _in general_ this is the kind of thing where you'll use an explicit decorator, possibly by composing reactive streams, that does the same thing that the Spring proxy-based decorators did.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It is a usual method call, there is no Reactive streams yet. The method returns the same object that it returned before migrating